# Cases Expression Being Weird

Tags: pattern-matching

Yes, your favorite impossible integral is back! But all jokes aside, why does this `Cases` command return empty brackets?

```
Cases[Integrate[Exp[-2 t^2] t^(9/5) (-t + x)^(4/5) HypergeometricPFQ[{1/2, 1}, {7/5, 19/10}, -3 t^2], {t, 0, x}], _Integrate]
```

If I put `Hold` on the `Integrate` wrapper, it correctly evaluates the pattern. I can't use `Hold` because I want to see first if *Mathematica* is able to evaluate the integral first. Since it can't evaluate this integral, the header `Integrate` should still be present, and pattern evaluate with the expression.

Thanks for any help! Cheers.

Comment: Because the default level spec for `Cases` is `{1}`.